# Variables address in Assembly

Tags: variables, assembly, memory

I comeback to Assembly and I can't resolve my problem with variables. 
I wrote super simple program and I can't figure why it doesn't work.

```
msg db 'a'
mov ah, 0Eh
mov al, [msg]
int 10h
```

I compile it into .com file and I use debug command in DOS to check what's going on and I see something like this

```
119A:0100 61     DB 61
119A:0101 B40E   MOV AH, 0E
119A:0103 A00000 MOV AL, [0000]
119A:0106 CD10   INT 10H
```

My question is why 0000 address variable going to the AL when my variable is on the 0100? I tried to use org instruction and setting ds register but it doesn't work. And please don't say that I have to use segments becasue I'm writing a bootloader without this NASM stuff and I try to understand how addressing wokrs.

Comment: Try to put a `org 100h` directive on top of your program.  Otherwise `nasm` assumes that the origin is `0`.

Comment: @fuz Oh... thank you

Comment: If you don't like segmentation (or don't want to learn it until after you know more basics), you could write programs or functions that run in 32-bit or 64-bit mode in user-space under a normal OS like Linux or Windows.  Then you have a flat memory model and symbols Just Work like they're supposed to.

Comment: IIRC, execution starts at `100h`, but you have data there, not code.  You don't need to load single bytes from RAM, you can use an immediate constant.  e.g. `mov al, 'a'`, but otherwise put your data at the end of your program or `jmp` over it.

Comment: JFYI as you can see from the `debug` output, you are trying to execute the byte 0x61 ('a' letter) as first instruction. Would you put there `db 195` instead of `db 'a'` you would terminate your COM file immediately (because `195` is `ret` instruction opcode). (luckily for you `db 0x61` looks like invalid opcode, so it will get probably skipped by CPU and the next instruction `mov ah,..` is executed as expected, but with some other data you may easily produce some valid opcodes with random instructions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I compile it into **.com** file
>
> I'm writing a **bootloader**

These two don't go together well! The .COM file format (requiring the `ORG 100h` directive) is a DOS thing, but since you're writing a bootloader there won't be any DOS to execute your program.

Your bootloader program will be loaded to memory by BIOS and the execution needs to start from the top. Of course this mean that at that first offset address there must be executable instructions and not the static data like in your current program.

One solution is to jump over this data:

```
jmps MyStart    ; EB 01     'jmp short'
msg  db 'a'     ; 61
MyStart:
mov  ah, 0Eh    ; B4 0E
mov  al, [msg]  ; A0 02 00  <-- offset is 0002h
int  10h        ; CD 10
```

In order to setup `DS` correctly you can write:

```
ORG  7C00h
jmps MyStart    ; EB 01     'jmp short'
msg  db 'a'     ; 61
MyStart:
xor  ax, ax     ; 30 C0
mov  ds, ax     ; 8E D8
mov  ah, 0Eh    ; B4 0E
mov  al, [msg]  ; A0 02 7C  <-- offset is 7C02h  
int  10h        ; CD 10
```

`ORG 7C00h` is your promess to the assembler that this program will be loaded in memory at an offset address of 7C00h.

Because BIOS loads it at linear address 0000:7C00h, setting the `DS` segment register to zero is the correct way to complete this particular `ORG`.